# symfony 1.4: How to fetch records from relation table

Tags: orm, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

How to get objects from the "many" table record?

I have list of `rsObjectComments` and I need to fetch `rsObjects`.

For example:

schema.yml:

```
rsObject:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~ 
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    description:  { type: string(6000), notnull: true }
  relations:
    rsObjectComments:
     class:        rsObjectComments
     local:        id
     foreign:      rsobject_id
     type:         many
     foreignAlias: Comments

rsObjectComments:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    rsobject_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    fromname: { type: string(100), notnull:true }
    fromemail: { type: string(100), notnull:true }
    comments: { type: string(1000), notnull:true }    
    is_public: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 1 }
  relations:
    rsObject: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: rsobject_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: rsObjectCommentsAlias }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encourage you to read the whole documentation page called: [Inside The Model Layer (Doctrine)](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Doctrine) (specially the part *Retrieving Related Record*).

You will see a basic example of article with many comments (which is almost the same as yours).

For your example, if you have a `rsObject` you can fetch related `rsObjectComments` using:

```
// will return a Doctrine_Collection
$rsObjectComments = $rsObject->getComments();
```

I'm using `getComments` because you defined the `foreignAlias` with `Comments`.

And if you want to work on them

```
foreach ($rsObject->getComments() as $comment)
{
  // $comment is a rsObjectComments object
}
```

And in the reverse order, if you have a comment and want to retrieve its article.

```
$rsObject = $comment->getRsObject();
```